# Vue3 + Vite + Pinia + new to Vue, having a hard time making the store functionalities work

Tags: vuejs3, vuex, pinia

Having trouble making Pinia work following the documentation and cheat sheet. It doesn't say WHERE to put WHAT and HOW. So I'm a bit lost, and newish to Vue too.

I'm trying to set up a series of dropdowns (I'm just including "city" here) and a Google map that can take that data and display it. But I can't get the store working.

Just a little note, please remember that other people have different learning styles and some, like me, have learning disabilities. So what might seem like a "dumb" question might be challenging with someone with my disabilities. Thanks!

**src/main.js**

```
import './assets/main.css'
import './scss/styles.scss'
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap'

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'

import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(createPinia())
app.use(router)

app.mount('#app')
```

**src/stores/incidentStore.js**

```
    import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
    import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useIncidentStore = defineStore('incidentData', {
  state: () => ({
    ALL_DATA: {},
    selectedCity: '',
    selectedLocation: '',
    selectedReason: '',
    selectedCondition: '',
    selectedType: ''
  }),
  getters: {},
  actions: {
    setData(data) {
      this.ALL_DATA = data
    },
    setCity(city) {
      this.selectedCity = city
    },
    setLocation(location) {
      this.selectedLocation = location
    },
    setReason(reason) {
      this.selectedReason = reason
    },
    setCondition(condition) {
      this.selectedCondition = condition
    },
    setType(type) {
      this.selectedType = type
    }
  }
})
```

**SomeComponent.vue**

```
<script setup>
import { useIncidentStore } from '../stores/IncidentStore'
const store = useIncidentStore()
</script>

<template>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="i_city">City</label>
      <select
        v-model="city"
        class="form-control"
        id="i_city"
        @change="($event) => store.setCity(city)"
      >
        <option v-for="y in dropdownData.cities" :value="y">
          {{ y }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
    </form>
 </template>


<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      city: null
      dropdownData: {
        cities: []
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchDropdownData()
  },
  methods: {
 
    fetchDropdownData() {
      const re =
        /\bIn|East of|West of|South of|North of|North West of|South West of|North East of|South East of|Near/gi
      fetch(`${import.meta.env.VITE_API_VERBOSE}`)
        .then((response) => {
          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok')
          }
          return response.json()
        })
        .then((data) => {
          // Create a new reactive object using Vue.set or spread operator
          this.dropdownData = {
            cities: new Set(data.map((el) => el.city.substring(0, 50)).sort())
          }
          console.log('this.dropDownData', this.dropdownData)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // Handle error
          console.error('Error:', error)
        })
    },
    getData() {
    
      console.log('selected_city', store.selectedCity)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**ERRORS:**
[image]

Literally no way that I try to set this up following these bizarro instructions make this work as advertised. How is this "easier" than VUEX??

So what do I need to do to get the dropdown menu to set the city **and then show it in the console log at the bottom in getData()?**

So, first error is solved, probably, but second error now says that `"store is not defined"` in the method getData(). Is there some magic trick I need to actually display the data? Thanks!

[image: Store Not Defined in the getData() method.]

Comment: Yes, I suppose that's a point. I should change it to "How the *&^% do I make sense of the documentation and set up and use a Pinia instance?" But I can't change the title now.

Comment: ok, I'll do that. I just get frustrated both with terrible documentation and sometimes with SO. Thanks for your help solving this.

Comment: ok, all done now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This attempt to call `store.setCityValue()` here:

```js
@change="($event) => store.setCityValue(city)"
```

does not work because there is no action on the store called `setCityValue`

```js
actions: {
    setData(data) {
      this.ALL_DATA = data
    },
    setCity(city) {
      this.selectedCity = city
    },
    setLocation(location) {
      this.selectedLocation = location
    },
    setCity(reason) {
      this.selectedReason = reason
    },
    setCondition(condition) {
      this.selectedCondition = condition
    },
    setType(type) {
      this.selectedType = type
    }
  }
```

There are two actions called `setCity`.  I think maybe the first one just needs it's name changed to `setCityValue`

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. @yoduh I have changed it so many times trying to get it to work I must have missed that. The second one was supposed to be setReason. Changing the name got rid of the first error but when I try to console.log store.selectedCity at the end I get an error that "store does not exist" (added at the bottom)

Comment: Your new error is due to the fact that you're using both `<script setup>` (Composition API) and `<script>` (Options API).  The store you've defined in the former, but it is not available in the latter (data/methods from both scripts are available in the template).  While it is possible to use both together, it is highly advised to stick with one Vue API syntax except for the cases listed in the [Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#usage-alongside-normal-script) for when you might use both.

Comment: If you prefer the Options API you can use Pinia with it following [this page of the documentation](https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/options-api.html)

Comment: Seriously? It's that complicated just to get data from a store? I'm also new to Vue, so I didn't realize there were two types of ways of using script tags and that they can't be mixed, and the documentation assumes you know that. Thanks!

Comment: Also not working for me:  1.   computed: {
    ...mapStores(useIncidentStore)
  }, 2.    async getCityData() {
      await this.incidentDataStore.selectedCity
    },, and I'm getting that useIncidentStore is not defined. Should I put it somewhere else other than compute and methods? See, this is  so NOT easy. It's the opposite of easy.

Comment: Also added <script>
import { createPinia, mapStores } from 'pinia' .... etc </script> , I still get "NcdotData.vue:83 Uncaught ReferenceError: useIncidentStore is not defined"

Comment: Try reviewing my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-lt6dfm?file=src%2Fstores%2FincidentStore.js,src%2FApp.vue&terminal=dev).  It's a very simplified version using Pinia, the Options API and your `incidentStore.js` code.  I'm not sure where your error is from your comments.  When I personally run into trouble, I try to simplify things down to bare minimum working code then work my way up from there, and I tend to use **a lot** of console.logging :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. That did it, with just a little adaptation for my needs. Much appreciated @yoduh